# Typecasting to UILabel in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an `NSArray` made of `UILabel`s that I initialized with this statement (the actual pointer is created in the .h file):

```
interLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:inter1,inter2,inter3, nil];
```

Later on I have an `IBAction` method that responds and is supposed to update the array of labels when a button is clicked:

```
-(IBAction)intervalButton:(id)sender{
    int count = 0;
    double val[3];
    if(count < 3){
        val[count] = number;
        [interLabels objectAtIndex:count].text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", val[count]];
        count++;
    }
}
```

However, `[interLabels objectAtIndex:count]` doesn't seem to be recognized as a `UILabel` object, so I get a compiler error that states that the property "text" cannot be found on object type "id." How can I get the compiler to recognize this as a `UILabel`? Is this an issue that can be solved by typecasting?

Comment: Please show how you are declaring the labels in your header file, and how you are synthesizing in your implementation file.

Comment: Simplest (clearest) fix is to assign the array element to a temp UILabel pointer, then use `text` on that.  You can instead do a cast, but the code gets opaque pretty fast when you try that (and you're already fairly opaque).

Comment: (You should always quote the EXACT error message you're getting.)

Comment: You should update to modern array syntax - `interLabels = @[inter1, inter2, inter3];`, `interlabels[count]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objectAtIndex returns you an reference of type 'id'. You need to cast it to UILabel before the  compiler / IDE will recognise the text property.

E.g. 
    ((UILabel*) [interLabels objectAtIndex:count]).text = ...

Comment: Or just use the method call notation, `[interlabels[count] setText:...]`.

Answer (score 0):

Type `id` does not need to be casted if you assign it to another variable. And in your case i think it would be nicer since you actually do two things, first get a object from the array and then changes state on that object. Consider this.

```
    -(IBAction)intervalButton:(id)sender
    {
        for ( UILabel *label in interLabels )
        { 
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", number];
        }
    }
```

I assumed you wanted a loop not a if statement since the if statement always evaluated to YES. Also i assumed `number` is a instance variable in your class.

Actually when i looked at the code again you can probably remove most of it.

Comment: I did actually want an if-statement, because basically I want the button click to have an effect 3 times on 3 different things respectively and then stop having an effect. But casting like Ben Clayton suggested and assigning to a variable like you suggested both did the trick. Thank you both!

Comment: then you need to make your count variable static. As it is now it will be reset to 0 each time the method is called.